# Android pass data from class to service

Tags: android

How to pass value of string from class to background service ? I have created android application to read ip address from url and I want to pass value from textResult string to STREAM_URL inside background service! How can I do that ?

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener
{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String STREAM_URL;
    final String textSource = "http://audiophileradio.stream/Ip.txt";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        new MyTask().execute();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        String textResult;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            URL textUrl;

            try {
                textUrl = new URL(textSource);

                BufferedReader bufferReader
                        = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

                String StringBuffer;
                String stringText = "";
                while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringText += StringBuffer;
                }
                bufferReader.close();

                textResult = stringText;
                return textResult;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Log.d("DebugTag", "Value: " + textResult);

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BackgroundService.this);
            String radio = sharedPreferences.getString("station", "8000");

            if (radio != null && radio.equals("8000"))
            {
                STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8000/";
            }
            if (radio != null && radio.equals("8010"))
            {
                STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8010/";
            }
            if (radio != null && radio.equals("8020"))
            {
                STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8020/";
            }
            if (radio != null && radio.equals("8030"))
            {
                STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8030/";
            }

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                try
                {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                        {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(BackgroundService.this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so what you are facing? how you pass this data?
you should get shared value in `onBind()`

Comment: Try this to make one `public static String RESULT_URL = "Default";` in service and when result comes change that with value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the opPostExecute of the aynctask, you can use the result string of. The UI thread. You could also set a global variable in the class to be set with the value in onPostExecute.

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
     new MyTask().execute();
     return START_STICKY;
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    String textResult;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        URL textUrl;

        try {
            textUrl = new URL(textSource);

            BufferedReader bufferReader
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

            String StringBuffer;
            String stringText = "";
            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();

            textResult = stringText;
            return textResult;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textResult = e.toString();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.d("DebugTag", "Value2: " + textResult);

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        STREAM_URL = result;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BackgroundService.this);
    String radio = sharedPreferences.getString("station", "8000");

    if (radio != null && radio.equals("8000"))
    {
        STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8000/";
    }
    if (radio != null && radio.equals("8010"))
    {
        STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8010/";
    }
    if (radio != null && radio.equals("8020"))
    {
        STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8020/";
    }
    if (radio != null && radio.equals("8030"))
    {
        STREAM_URL = "http://178.149.88.126:8030/";
    }

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try
    {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(BackgroundService.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I add Log.d("DebugTag", "Value0: " + STREAM_URL); inside service onCreate method I get null value!!!

Comment: You should change thee Asynctask to return a string so `MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` turns to `MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>`, then return the result in the do while.

Comment: When I change to AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> method Void doInBackground(Void... params) show error attempting to use incompatible return type !!!

Comment: Ah, change the return type of `doInBackground` to `String` from `Void`. Also make sure `onPostExecute` takes in a `String` instead on `Void`.

Comment: Still same error and incompatible type error for return textResult; !!!

Comment: Also, since do in background works on another thread, you may still get null since the asynctask may still be working before you get the result back. You can fix that by doing the `get()` method of asynctask, but that will run your thread in the uiThread.

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: You should move everything except the `new MyTask().execute()` from the `onCreate` method to the `onPostExecute`.

Comment: getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); in PreferenceManager cannot be applied to MyTask !!!

Comment: Since you are inside another class, you would need to change `getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` to `getDefaultSharedPreferences(BackgroundService.this)`

Comment: @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) null pointer exception!!!!!!

Comment: Since that code is in `onStartCommand`, the `mediaPlayer` is null since it hasnt gotten a value from the `Asysnctask yet` I will rewrite the code to show how it should be.

Comment: Why did you remove commands inside onStartCommand in your code ?

Comment: Since the code inside `onStartCommand` was using `mediaPlayer`, you were getting a null pointer exception, since it wasn't set until the `onPostExecute`. Moving all the code into the `onPostExecute` ensures that it won't be null when you try to use it.

Comment: How to fix that ?

Comment: Radio didn't work because I forgot to add http:// in ip address after reading it from url !!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using broadcast receiver following is the example

```
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;


    public class TempService extends Service {

        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("UpdateUrl")) {
                        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("urlNew")) {
                            String newUrl = bundle.getString("urlNew");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("UpdateUrl");
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(broadcastReceiver!=null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    }
```

And where from update put following code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("UpdateUrl");
intent.putExtra("urlNew", "" + newUrl);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service audiophileradio.example.com.audiophileradio.BackgroundService has leaked IntentReceiver

Comment: Now I update my code, Sorry I forgot unregister Receiver in onDestroy(), If this help then vote up and accept.

Comment: In updated code media player won't start!!!Problem starts in mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener !!!